# Solving a system of nonlinear ODE in matrix form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am interested in the following equation for $v(t) \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$, $m > 1$:

$v' = -A \cdot v^m,$

where $A$ is a positive-definite and symmetric matrix, and $v^m$ denotes componentwise exponentiation. Under what conditions may this system of nonlinear ODEs be solved explicitly, and what can be said about the asymptotics of the solutions?

Comment: In what context would you use this equation?

Comment: It's difficult to explain in full, but the values of the vector $v$ describe the approximate sizes of some 'necks' in a geometric flow. Since the form of the equation is quite simple, I hoped that perhaps it had been studied before.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a diagonal matrix. The system is decoupled. Each component is a separable ordinary differential equation. You can determine the solution analytically.

Comment: Yes, that's true. What if the matrix is not diagonal, though?

Comment: Then it is unlikely that you will find a solution.